# Which chapter of the manga does Season 2 of Jujutsu Kaisen anime end in?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

If I want to keep following Jujutsu Kaisen story in the manga, after the second season of the anime ended, which chapter of the manga the anime do I have to read?

Which chapter of the manga does Season 2 of Jujutsu Kaisen anime end in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this website](https://eiga-manga.com/entry/jujutsu-shibuyajihen-anime), the 2nd series deals with 渋谷事変, which ends in Chapters 136-137 of Volume 16.